# Table with scroll and auto size columns

Tags: html, css, overlay

I have a table like this with scroll with overlay (only for Chrome):

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/t0pmjny6/2/

The important css is:

```
table.scroll {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

table.scroll tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:180px;
    overflow-y:overlay;
}

table.scroll thead, table.scroll tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

The class `overlay` works only for Chrome an FF, I know, that's ok. The problem with that table is if some text is too long, it overflow the `th` or `td` width.

I would like to see my table like this but:

https://jsfiddle.net/pmiranda/29z5hn06/2/

...BUT with scroll working like in the previous table

Any suggestion?

Comment: Change table-layout to auto

Comment: @trenccan no, that won't work, try it on the fiddle. Each row will have it own size.

Comment: try to look here http://jsfiddle.net/f2XYF/8/, you could arrange your table in the same way. I think this is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
table.scroll {
    display: inline-block;
    table-layout:auto;
    max-height:180px;
    overflow-y:overlay;
    width: auto;
}

table.scroll thead, table.scroll tbody tr {
    width:100%;
}

th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    background: #fff;
}
```

You can't set the height of a table unless you set its display to block.

https://jsfiddle.net/yxfsj4c6/

Comment: Almost! the thead should be fixed, the scroll is only for the tbody

Comment: I think now it is ok. You can check the new jsfiddle link.

Comment: Works good. The only problem is the width, I need the cells to full the available width. If the content is not enough, I will have a blank space in the table: https://i.imgur.com/GPvXsLl.png  but this is the best (and only) answer, so I would pick as the correct one

Comment: Can you check the new jsfiddle link?

Comment: Maybe you have some other css rules. I think you should try to add to table.scroll width: auto;

Comment: But check your own fiddle, happens the same

Comment: Much better, now I can keep working from all what you posted. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. I'm glad to help you out. If you have any question, I will help you, if I can. :)

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this code here:**

you just add an extra div for wrapping the table, and talk the div is you expected height or max-height.

```css
.table-wrap {
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
table.scroll {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.scroll thead,
table.scroll thead tr {
    background: #fff;
}
table.scroll thead tr th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
    <table class="scroll">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Año</th>
                <th>Mes</th>
                <th>Obra</th>
                <th>Tipooooooo oooooooooo ooooo ooooooo</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                <th>Imp. Nómina</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Julio</td>
                <td>EDIFICIO FARELLONES</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>52</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_1" value="2018072507">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Agosto</td>
                <td>EDIFICIO SUCRE</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_2" value="2018082803">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Junio</td>
                <td>EDIFICIO TRANSOCEANICA 2</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>45</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_3" value="2018062703">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Junio</td>
                <td>HANNOVER 2 Y 3</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_4" value="2018062803">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Junio</td>
                <td>OTOÑAL</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_5" value="2018062904">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Julio</td>
                <td>MONTENOVA</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_6" value="2018070408">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Julio</td>
                <td>HOMECENTER ÑUÑOA</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_7" value="2018071906">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Julio</td>
                <td>HOMECENTER ÑUÑOA</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_8" value="2018072413">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2018</td>
                <td>Julio</td>
                <td>EDIFICIO MATUCANA I</td>
                <td>PROGRAMA OFTALMOLOGICO</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mensual" class="check_social_mensual" id="checkbox_social_mensual_9" value="2018072409">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

> ***Note:*** This code works fine but position sticky not support old browser see this https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

Comment: But the snippet shows the same table, with each column having the same width, and the text on the 3rd and 4th column with overflowing the size. Look at the 2nd fiddle that I put in my question, the columns are auto size.

Comment: this happened when the word is larger than the td element. you can use the select 'td' and use 'word-break: break-all' simple CSS code example: "  table.scroll tr td {  word-break: break-all; } "

Comment: Also you add your flexable fontsize

Comment: That's why I need the table as the 2nd link, because the columns with adjust to the content

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky this link for support browser CSS property, every browser not support same CSS property this this one of the cross-browser purpose

Comment: I know... but I need `overlay` this should work only for Chrome

Comment: you can give me screenshot

Comment: What I need is what I put in the question: the 2nd fiddle BUT with scroll, that's all. The 2nd fiddle has auto size columns, your examples doesn't have that.